# how to do multiple sort in csv using pandas and filter particular value?

Tags: python, sorting, csv, pandas

**csv file to be read**
**file name:salaries.csv**
**Q:sort cities by descending order of lawyer salary.**
City,Job,Salary
Delhi,Doctors,500
Delhi,Lawyers,400
Delhi,Plumbers,100
London,Doctors,800
London,Lawyers,700
London,Plumbers,300
Tokyo,Doctors,900
Tokyo,Lawyers,800
Tokyo,Plumbers,400
Lawyers,Doctors,300
Lawyers,Lawyers,400
Lawyers,Plumbers,500
Hong Kong,Doctors,1800
Hong Kong,Lawyers,1100
Hong Kong,Plumbers,1000
Moscow,Doctors,300
Moscow,Lawyers,200
Moscow,Plumbers,100
Berlin,Doctors,800
Berlin,Plumbers,900
Paris,Doctors,900
Paris,Lawyers,800
Paris,Plumbers,500
Paris,Dog catchers,400
**output ex**
Tokyo,800
London,700
Delhi,400
...

Comment: @MohitBhasi If not interested please stay away instead of wasting time posting such comments.There are people to help.You are discouraging and hurting.

Comment: I am suggesting you to put in some effort and give it a try , I am not trying to be offensive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df[df.Job == 'Lawyers'].sort('Salary', ascending=False).City
>>>
13    Hong Kong
7         Tokyo
21        Paris
4        London
1         Delhi
10      Lawyers
16       Moscow
```